# Does anyone know how to triangulate location using Arduino and SIM900?

Tags: gps, location, arduino, gsm

I have a SIM900 and Arduino Leonardo. using the SIM900.h library I have it all working and receiving text messages, etc however I'm wondering how I can use it to either grab all the local tower information or grab the same and triangulate the LAT, LONG, ETC from that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about the local tower (and for a few neighboring towers) with the AT+CENG=2 command. This include things like tower ID and signal level. You'll need to know the geographic location of these towers and do the triangulation yourself.

I suggest you take a look at this project: http://www.open-electronics.org/mini-gsm-localizer-without-gps/. It has an open-source firmware that you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s sequence of AT commands needed to get location of module:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS" // set bearer parameter
OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet" // set apn
OK

AT+SAPBR=1,1 // activate bearer context
OK

AT+SAPBR=2,1 // get context ip address
+SAPBR: 1,1,"10.151.43.104"
OK

AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1 // triangulate
+CIPGSMLOC: 0,19.667806,49.978185,2014/03/20,14:12:27

OK
```

Location is not acurrate though, first test got me coordinates located around 4 kilometers away from my place. Usually it’s not that bad, enough for simple applications.

Comment: The last location is the tower coordinates not the module's.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AT+COPS? command to reach location of tower. the 4-digit number expresses the location. for decode the number yıu should use LAC.

i.e +CGREG: 1, A9F0, 200D6E 
(the second term A9F0 is the location number of tower)